# how can I retrieve words back from word mapping using numpy array? [Tensorflow RNN] Text classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Here's what I have:

```
vocab_processor = skflow.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor(MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH)
X_train = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(X_train)))
X_test = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(X_test)))
```

Now,It creates a numpy array of ids of words in word dictionary.
What should I do if I want to retrieve those words back from the dictionary?

There is a function called `reverese(document)` but it doesn't work in this case. It is returning list containing  marker.

```
['What is most beautiful in <UNK> men is something feminine'
"The camera makes everyone a tourist in other people's reality"
'<UNK> in reality is the worst of all evils because' ...,
'<UNK> aware that no bank would do this as they'
'<UNK> keep sending you many details through the post like'
'<UNK> banking transactions should be conducted in a secure place']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you **id: word**

```
w_dict = {v:k for k,v in vocab_processor.vocabulary_._mapping.items()}
```

Then you can get the words:

```
words = w_dict.values()
```